# CryptoJS.AES.encrypt Go equivalent

Tags: go, aes, cryptojs

I am trying to encode string in golang equivalent to javascript cryptoJs library, but result is not same when encrypt with golang and javascript!

this snippet creates a 128-bit cipher in js

javascript code:

```js
let message = 'I need encrypt this message with CryptoJS.AES.encrypt and decrypt with Golang AES package';
let key = 'key created dynamically and key.length not in AES length standard';


// convert to word array
message = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(message)
key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key)

// create hash
const hash = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, key, {
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding
    }).ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)
```

in this snippet cryptoJs aes encrypt function accept key string with different size, but in golang aes package only accept standard size like 16,32.

Comment: No chance, the CryptoJS code processes too long or too short keys due to a [bug](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/issues/293), but the obtained ciphertext is not AES compliant. It is different if you use a password (which happens automatically if the key material is passed as string and not as WordArray). In this case CryptoJS applies a key derivation (`EVP_BytesToKey`), which can also be used in the Go code (there are several implementations on the web).